# What is the proper way to define custom attributes for conditional compilation?

Tags: testing, rust, conditional-compilation

I'd like to be able to pass a flag to `cargo test` to enable logging in my tests, when I need to debug them.

I've come up with something like:

```rust
#[cfg(logging)]
// An internal module where I define some helper to configure logging
// I use `tracing` internally.
use crate::logging;

#[test]
fn mytest() {
    #[cfg(logging)]
    logging::enable();
    // ..
    assert!(true);
}
```

Then I can enable the logs with

```
RUSTFLAGS="--cfg logging" cargo test
```

It works but it feels like I'm abusing the `rustc` flag system. It also has the side effect of recompiling all the crates with my `logging` flag, which (besides the fact that it takes ages) may be an issue if this flag is used by one of my dependency some day.

Is there a better way to define and use custom attributes? I could add a `feature` to my cargo manifest, but this is not really a feature since it's just for the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't usually recompile your application, there's no need to: you can use an environment variable. For example:

```
if std::env::var("MY_LOG").is_ok() {
    logging::enable();
}
```

You can then dynamically decide to log by calling your application with

```
MY_LOG=true cargo run
```

or, when already compiled,

```
MY_LOG=true myapp
```

You would usually configure more than just whether the log is on, for example the log level or the level destination. Here's a real example: https://github.com/Canop/broot/blob/master/src/main.rs#L20

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question directly, it seems to be the right way to go wrt to my original problem of enabling/disabling the logs, so I accepted it. Thanks!